# Keras Tokenizer

Tags: tensorflow, keras

anyone have idea how exactly does kera.preprocessing.text.Tockenizer work?

```
word_index = tokenizer.word_index
print('Found %s unique tokens.' % len(word_index))
data = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=maxlen)
labels = np.asarray(labels)
print('Shape of data tensor:', data.shape)
print('Shape of label tensor:', labels.shape)
indices = np.arange(data.shape[0])
np.random.shuffle(indices)
data = data[indices]
labels = labels[indices]
x_train = data[:training_samples]
y_train = labels[:training_samples]
x_val = data[training_samples: training_samples + validation_samples]
y_val = labels[training_samples: training_samples + validation_samples]
```

> Found 88413 unique tokens. Shape of data tensor: (24984, 100) Shape of
>   label tensor: (24984,)

```
tokenizer.texts_to_sequences('You are Amrock!')
```

> Out[18]:
>   [[5128],  [1601],  [1205],  [],  [3],  [1480],  [962],  [],  [3], 
>   [1978],  [1480],  [1601],  [1144],  [2292],  []]

What does Out[18] mean exactly?

Comment: How are you running this? Are you using iPython or something else?

Comment: on jupyter notebook

Comment: I suspect it's the output from the 18th instruction.

Comment: out[18] only meaning the running 18th result..